# instance payment in paypal via button

Tags: paypal

i trying to get monney from paypal.

i have my own domine , and i created several button .

each of this button i insert into my application .  and when ever someone click on 
any button it will open paypal site and you can pay.

after you buyit , it will send you into my site and there it confirming your payment 
and update the data base.

its work 100% in sandbox.paypal.com

but when someone bought items from me. it didnt work at all . 
its send my site statuse of invalide after he pay his monney .
and sent to my paypal account asking to deliver it to him (pending statuse). 
i got all the information needed there like player number and stuff like that . 
but all the point is missing if i need to each payment enter to paypal put an statuse of "internet good" and then i need to update the database throw another script.

anyone know what i need to do to get over with all this prosses via scripting ? 
or any other way.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could show us some code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: but all my code is working . in sandbox. the only problem is that paypal want me to confirm that i want to get payment from the user . pending statuse.

Comment: First you can try this… When you’re logged into your Paypal account go to:

Profile > My selling preferences > Block payments > change the first setting “Block payments in a currency I do not hold” to “No, accept them and convert them”

Comment: thanks you very very much!!!! I couldn't find it anywhere .. thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer was in the comments:

First you can try this… When you’re logged into your Paypal account go to:

Profile > My selling preferences > Block payments > change the first setting “Block payments in a currency I do not hold” to “No, accept them and convert them”